# CSS breaking when comments added

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add comments to my HTML style, but I'm finding that when I add a comment, the styles stop working.

The below works just fine.  The icon and the text display in gray.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <link href="/gtd/media/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>

            .action-star {
                color: gray;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <span class="action-star"><i class="icon-star icon-large"></i> Test Icon</span>
        </div><!--/container-->
    </body>
</html>
```

However the below does not work.  The icon and the text display in black.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <link href="/gtd/media/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            <!-- Comment -->
            .action-star {
                color: gray;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <span class="action-star"><i class="icon-star icon-large"></i> Test Icon</span>
        </div><!--/container-->
    </body>
</html>
```

The only thing I added was the line:

```
<!-- Comment -->
```

I must be missing something obvious. . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make comments in CSS use `/* Comment */`, not the HTML `<!-- Comment -->` syntax. That is what is breaking your CSS.

Just as a hint, if you are working in an editor that supports syntax highlighting, usually they will give comments a specific color. The most common colors I have seen for comments are grey, dark blue, or dark green. Of course, this can still vary by editor, but a change in coloring is a good indicator that you are using the proper syntax for a comment.

Look how your `<!--/container-->` comment turned grey in your code sample, but `<!-- Comment -->` didn't. As you now know, this didn't happen because you hadn't used proper syntax.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Css comments are made `/* like this */`, not `<!-- like this -->`.

Answer (score 4):

Once youre within the `<style>` block, you have to use CSS syntax. For comments, this means using `/* Comment */`

Answer (score 2):

That's the styling for a HTML comment, use the CSS specific of `/* comment */`

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, a comment starts with /* and ends with */. Comments can span multiple lines, but may not be nested:

```
/* This is a single-line comment */

/* This is a comment that
   spans multiple lines */
```

According to the CSS2 specification, comments that appear between tokens won’t have any effect on the styles’ rendering. In practice, however, we find comments causing errors in some older browsers in certain situations.

The `//` comment syntax used in C++ is not allowed. Neither are SGML comments that take the form `<!-- … -->`, except in one situation: they may appear in internal style sheets—style sheets placed within the HTML source using the  tag—in order to hide the CSS statements from pre-HTML4 user agents. However, this use of comments is now redundant and can be disregarded